# Why find_in_set works but IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have code like this.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_deleteOrderData`(orderid BIGINT(11))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE shipmentnumbers VARCHAR(1000);
        DECLARE cartonid VARCHAR(1000);

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a_shipmentid) FROM t_shipment WHERE a_orderid = orderid INTO shipmentnumbers;

        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a_cartonid) FROM t_carton WHERE a_shipmentid IN (shipmentnumbers) INTO cartonid;

    SELECT shipmentnumbers;
    /*SELECT  cartonid;  */
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Here shipmentnumbers returns `100020,100021,100022`
Ideally cartonid should be returned as `11,12,13`

But i get only 11 as cartonid.

But when i use below code i get proper result.

```
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a_cartonid) FROM t_carton WHERE FIND_IN_SET( a_shipmentid, shipmentnumbers ) INTO cartonid;
```

I wanted to know what exactly is the difference between IN and FIND_IN_SET and hwo di i decide what to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` accepts a list or parameters to search, `FIND_IN_SET` accepts a string parameter containing a comma-separated list:

```
SELECT  1 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)

SELECT  FIND_IN_SET(1, '1,2,3,4')
```

If you try to apply `IN` to a comma-separated string, it will treat it as a single parameter and will match it as a whole:

```
SELECT  1 IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

Of course, the string `'1'` is not equal to the string `'1,2,3,4'` so the query above returns false.

Comment: how about this 
`SELECT  FIND_IN_SET("abc", 'abc','abd','asr','asd')` ? This will work right?

Answer (score 1):

`FIND_IN_SET` searches a string inside a set of string separated by a comma.

- [MySQL FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

But you don't need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate the rows to be used in the `IN` clause, try this,

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(a_cartonid) 
FROM    t_carton
WHERE   a_shipmentid IN
         (
            SELECT a_shipmentid
            FROM t_shipment 
            WHERE a_orderid = orderid
         )
```

or use `JOIN`

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.a_cartonid) 
FROM    t_carton a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT a_shipmentid
            FROM t_shipment 
            WHERE a_orderid = orderid
        ) b ON a.a_shipmentid = b.a_shipmentid
```