# Using SELECT result in subselect IN()

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The following query works (example query below)

```
SELECT cat, dog, mouse, ids,
    (SELECT cheese
    FROM my_second_table AS a
    WHERE a.ids IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    LIMIT 1) AS cheese
FROM my_first_table
```

It gives me back the 5 columns with the correct data as I'd expect, including the cheese column.

The following query does not work, cheese column is always empty

```
SELECT cat, dog, mouse, ids,
    (SELECT cheese
    FROM my_second_table AS a
    WHERE a.ids IN (ids)
    LIMIT 1) AS cheese
FROM my_first_table
```

`ids` contains the same comma separated numbers as in the first query above, retrieved from each row in the `my_first_table`.

I feel this should work and that I am doing something wrong. Is it OK to use the SELECT results in a Sub-Select IN() clause?

Comment: Can you give how to store value in `ids` ?

Comment: I guess `ids` is a single string value. It won't work like that.

Comment: @dragoste Correct, why not? It's just `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Comment: Because it's not PHP or smth like that. ;-) MySQL puts it into the query like `\`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\`` - escaped, as single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with find_in_set function like

```
SELECT cat, dog, mouse, ids,
    (SELECT cheese
    FROM my_second_table AS a
    WHERE find_in_set(a.ids, ids)
    LIMIT 1) AS cheese
FROM my_first_table
```

> IN accepts a list or parameters to search, FIND_IN_SET accepts a string parameter containing a comma-separated list.

In your case `ids` are comma separated string so `find_in_set` will true and `IN` clause return false

Comment: @superphonic have tried this answer?

Comment: Yep just have, this works! Are there any drawbacks? What's the performance difference if any between this and `IN()`

Comment: There is no any perfomance difference and check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656740/why-find-in-set-works-but-in-clause for reference