# search number from string in php

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have problem to search number from string which is simple but I can not solve, I have GALLERY table

```
id | gallery_name | standard
____________________________
1  | aaa          | 1,2    
2  | bbb          | 2
3  | ccc          | 1,6, 12
```

I want to find gallery which has 2 standard.
For that I run below query

`select * from galley where standard IN('%2%')`;

Output: it return first two row which contain 2 standard and also return 3 row which not contain 2 but 12

Please help me how to solve the issue

Thank you

Comment: I think you should normalize your table, but failing that, have a look at `FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [need to filter data in mysql with data array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317342/need-to-filter-data-in-mysql-with-data-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either `FIND_IN_SET()` OR `LIKE`

```
select * from galley FIND_IN_SET('2',standard);
```

OR

```
select * from galley 
  where standard LIKE '%,2' OR standard LIKE '2,%' OR standard LIKE '%,2,%';
```

Comment: I don't think your LIKE example will work. It will still bring the last row which has '12'.

Comment: @AnjanaSilva thanks for your comment,just updated my answer

Comment: @AnjanaSilva LIKE Example works. It will not bring last row with 12

Comment: @PraveenS because I have updated my answer,thank you